# Why can't I start my project with the form I want in c# .net

Tags: c#, project

In my project there are many forms. I want to start my project with a specific form but my project only allows 1 form to be the initial form.

Why is that and how to fix it?

[image]

[image: oj]

Comment: You need to make the change in Program.cs.  To start the main form you need to call the constructor like : Application.Run(new Form1());

Comment: Only VB.NET needs that dropdown because it *hides*  `Program.cs` and the `Main` method. In C# you can just change the form that's displayed in code, even pick which one to display based on command line arguments or anything else you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Startup object` points to a class that contains the `Main` function. In your case, the `TeleDoc.FrmMain`.

Inside this class you'll find the `Main` method that somehow creates the main form of the app and shows it, e.g.

```
public static void Main()
{
        Application.Run(new TeleDoc());
}
```

The argument passed to the `Application.Run` points to a form that it created as the main app form. If you alter this code, you could either point to another form or even, point to any form depending on a custom condition.

Comment: Thanks I also added  using System.Windows.Forms;